# Is it possible add index to child tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

Let's suppose I have a parent table and another table that inherits from it in PostgreSQL 9.5. And then if I add an index to the parent table how do I make it propagated to the inheriting table?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id serial,
  data text
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  stuff text
) INHERITS (parent);

CREATE INDEX ix_parent_data ON parent(data);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/05ea2/1

Important note - the table is already created without `INCLUDING clause`.

Comment: You need to create the indexes on the child tables manually

Comment: INCLUDING is used with LIKE some_table, so I'm not sure of the relevance unless the actual tables are LIKE not INHERITS.